# How can I close off a toilet drain in a concrete floor

Tags: bathroom, concrete, slab, laundry

I want to remove the toilet and turn the bathroom into a laundry room.

How can I close off the drain?

Comment: There are covers which attach to that fitting the same way a toilet does. I've got one of those in my basement;  was there when I moved in and I've had no reason to disturb it.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding drain plug, fits into inside diameter of pipe than expands to seal when the nut is tightened.[image]

Comment: After tightening, the wing nut can be removed and replaced with a low-profile hex nut. The threaded post can then be cut off to provide a low profile to eliminate tripping hazards. Check local code to see if you are allowed to cover over it. I believe some locales allow a cement or grout plug for permanent abandonment.

Comment: These are also sometimes called "test plugs".